# Regular Expression(Java) to extract href attribute value

Tags: java, regex

I have a tag in xml file like

```
<a href="/abc/xyz/ccc" id="link_abc" title="bala" name="link_abc"></a>
```

so i am storing this value in a string called tempString;
Now i have to parse the tempString so that i can extract only href attribute value.
the output i am expecting is  /abc/xyz/ccc. I am looking for Java regular expression for doing this.

I would really appreciate your help on this.

Regards,
Ramakrishna.

Comment: @DNA: first he'd need to make sure that the HTML was in proper XML form such as by becoming XHTML compliant. Or even easier, simply use an HTML parser.

Comment: XML is similar to HTML in the difficulty of parsing it using regular expressions, so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Argh, I'd resisted the urge to link to [THAT PAGE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)....

Comment: Let me give you back ground. While unmarshalling(JAXB) the Link property has below value.                                              Link = <a href="/abc/xyz/ccc" id="link_abc" title="bala" name="link_abc"></a>;                                                             Now i have to extract href attribute value and reassign it to Link property. May be the only option i can see is using Java Regular expression. I couln't use any other API.

Comment: @user1635014 have you tried my approach ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) ?

i.e :

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://yoururl.com/").get();
Elements link = doc.select("#link_abc");
String href = link.attr("href");
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use String.split();

```
    String h = "<a href=\"/abc/xyz/ccc\" id=\"link_abc\" title=\"bala\"   name=\"link_abc\">planx</a>";
System.out.println(h.split("href")[1].substring(2).split("\"")[0]);


OUTPUT: /abc/xyz/ccc
```